# How can I create a field in SQL that is dynamically valued based on its own dataset?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have created a query in SQL, using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

The query provides a list of employees, their supervisor and a job title.

Here is an example with sample data:

```
+----------------+----------------+-----------------+
|    Employee    |   Supervisor   |    Job Title    |
+----------------+----------------+-----------------+
| Joe Bloggs     | Joe Bloggs     | Owner           |
| John Doe       | Joe Bloggs     | ESTIMATOR       |
| Jack Nimble    | Joe Bloggs     | ESTIMATOR       |
| Tom Hanks      | John Doe       | Admin           |
| Les Mis        | Tom Hanks      | IT Tech         |
| Bruce Lee      | Tom Hanks      | Mechanic        |
| Norman Gunston | Jack Nimble    | Accountant      |
| Fred Flinstone | John Doe       | Web Designer    |
| Brady North    | Norman Gunston | Receptionist    |
| Chris Pork     | Norman Gunston | Accountant      |
| Tom Cruise     | Tom Hanks      | General Manager |
| Jason Smith    | Jack Nimble    | IT Tech         |
| John Howard    | Tom Hanks      | Trainer         |
+----------------+----------------+-----------------+.
```

As you can see, the employees can have a supervisor that is also in the same list of employees. For example, Tom Hanks has a supervisor called John Doe who is an employee with a supervisor called Joe Bloggs.

In this case, Joe Bloggs is his own supervisor because he owns the company.

This is the SQL Code that produced the above results:

```
select HRRMName.FullName as 'Employee', HRRM.udSupervisor1 as 'Supervisor', HRPC.JobTitle from HRRM
LEFT JOIN HRPC
ON HRPC.HRCo = HRRM.HRCo and HRPC.PositionCode = HRRM.PositionCode
LEFT JOIN HRRMName ON HRRMName.HRCo = HRRM.HRCo and HRRMName.HRRef = HRRM.HRRef
where HRRM.HRCo = 1 and HRRM.ActiveYN = 'Y'
```

My goal is to use SSRS to develop an company organization chart however, first I need to amend my dataset (query) by adding a new field called 'level'.

The 'level' field will be an integer. It will start at 1 for the owner of the company and then 2 for the employees under him and then 3 for the employees under them and so on.

Here is an example of how the new results would look:

```
+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-------+
|    Employee    |   Supervisor   |    Job Title    | Level |
+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-------+
| Joe Bloggs     | Joe Bloggs     | Owner           |     1 |
| John Doe       | Joe Bloggs     | ESTIMATOR       |     2 |
| Jack Nimble    | Joe Bloggs     | ESTIMATOR       |     2 |
| Tom Hanks      | John Doe       | Admin           |     3 |
| Les Mis        | Tom Hanks      | IT Tech         |     4 |
| Bruce Lee      | Tom Hanks      | Mechanic        |     4 |
| Norman Gunston | Jack Nimble    | Accountant      |     3 |
| Fred Flinstone | John Doe       | Web Designer    |     3 |
| Brady North    | Norman Gunston | Receptionist    |     4 |
| Chris Pork     | Norman Gunston | Accountant      |     4 |
| Tom Cruise     | Tom Hanks      | General Manager |     4 |
| Jason Smith    | Jack Nimble    | IT Tech         |     3 |
| John Howard    | Tom Hanks      | Trainer         |     4 |
+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-------+
```

How is it possible to dynamically produce this value?

I was thinking of this Psuedo Code:

```
Declare @level int;
Set @level = 1;

IF table.employee = table.supervisor then table.level = @Level
@level ++
IF table.supervisor = table.employee where level = (@level - 1)  then table.level = @Level
@level ++
```

I am seeking advise on how to get the new dynamic row.

Answer (score 1):

You would do this with a recursive CTE.  I think the following does what you want:

```
with t as (<your query here>),
     cte as (
      select t.employee, t.supervisor, t.jobtitle, 1 as level, t.
      from t
      where employee = supervisor
      union all
      select t.employee, t.supervisor, t.jobtitle, level + 1
      from cte join
           t
           on t.supervisor = cte.employee and t.supervisor <> t.employee
     )
 select employee, supervisor, jobtitle
 from cte;
```